# Inheriting different class for production region

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I have 2 abstract class, one is for staging region and one is for production region.

```
public class Auth: StagingAuthProvider
{
/* code goes here*/
}
```

but every time I deploy in production, I  have to manually replace StagingAuthProvider with ProductionAuthProvider

```
public class Auth: ProductionAuthProvider
{
/* code goes here*/
}
```

also, i have flag  variable in appsetting

```
"IsStaging": true
```

what I want is when I make

```
"IsStaging": false
```

Auth class should automatically inherit the class

```
ProductionAuthProvider
```

I wonder how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: Move the base functionalities from the base class into a separate service and you register the correct one according to the flag. `Auth` now does not inherit from `*AuthProvider` but it has it as dependency (which will be resolved at run-time).

Comment: What dependency injection framework do you use?

Comment: @CodeCaster .net core

Comment: Maybe this page could be helpful to you: [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) ?